# your browser version is not supported using symfony browserkit

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, single-page-application

I'm trying to automate some features and I need to scarp a web page.

So, I'm using [browserkit](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html#making-external-http-requests) to make external request to website.

Everything seems good but there's no useful result in my response because target page is using modern JavaScript.

Let's take a look :

***PHP file***

```
require "./vendor/autoload.php";


use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$client = HttpClient::create([
    'max_redirects' => 7,
]);

$response = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl'
);

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();

$contentType = $response->getHeaders()['content-type'][0];

$content = $response->getContent();

dd($content); //dd() is installed globally on my php installation
```

and this is **`$content`** result:

```
^ """
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>


  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <title>System Zdalnej Rejestracji</title>


  <base href="/">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">


  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq ▶
<style>*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:no-preference){:root{scroll-behavior:smooth;}}body{margin:0;font-family:var(--bs-f ▶
<body>


  <!--[if lt IE 11]>


    <div style="padding: 1em; border-bottom: 1px solid #0052a5;">Serwis Ministerstwa Spraw Zagranicznych Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej</div>


    <div style="font-size: 1.5em; margin: 4em auto; max-width: 1024px; text-align: center;">


      <br />


      <p>Dear User,</p><br />


      <p>Your browser's version is not supported by the application.</p><br /><br />


      Please, actualize Your browser or use another one


    </div>


  <![endif]-->


  <app-root></app-root>


<script src="runtime.31b3be7ffe3f39288917.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.da272157cf92c2e29a93.js" defer></script><script src="main.375c8bb1538d8323b9 ▶


</body></html>
"""
```

and as you can see in this lines:

> ```
>   <p>Dear User,</p><br />
>
>
> <p>Your browser's version is not supported by the application.</p><br /><br />
>
>
> Please, actualize Your browser or use another one
> ```

***UPDATE:***

I did use `Browser` class either but there's same result:

```
$browser = new \Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create());
$browser->request('GET', 'https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl');
$response = $browser->getResponse();

dd($response);
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

And as a mention it's my first experience on web scraping so detailed answers are appreciated.

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by software (in this case the receiving webserver) validating your browser and to check if your browser can handle the website. It could be a solution to 'mimick' the request of a 'state of the art' browser. This can done by providing your request with a `User-Agent`.

Using `HttpClient` you can try the following:

```
$response = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl',
    [
       'headers' => [
            'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0',
       ],
    ]
);
```

Using `BrowserKit` you can try the following:

```
$browser
   ->setHttpHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0')
   ->request('GET','https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl');
```

The more you 'mimick' a normal request made by a regular visitor, the more lickely you will receive a decent response. Another example can be found [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/issues/401#issuecomment-591760247).

Comment: unfortunately that specific page is generated entirely using javascript (everything is in the `runtime.31b3be7ffe3f39288917.js` file), so unless the Browserkit developers created an actual javascript engine, you'll need a browser here (a headless browser works fine tho :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute javascript, use an actual web browser. I recommend the [chrome-php/chrome project](https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome)

> $ composer require chrome-php/chrome

One interesting note about the specific website you're scraping, it's entirely generated with Javascript, everything is in the `runtime.31b3be7ffe3f39288917.js` file, and the javascript is slow, using ~2-3 seconds to actually generate the page, the page is generated long after the `DOMContentLoaded` event is actually fired. try

```
declare(strict_types=1);
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
// chrome
$browserFactory = new \HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory('chromium');
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser([
    'headless' => true,
    'windowSize'   => [1920, 1080],
]);
$page = $browser->createPage();
$navigate = $page->navigate('https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl');
$navigate->waitForNavigation(\HeadlessChromium\Page::NETWORK_IDLE);
$html = $page->evaluate('document.documentElement.outerHTML')->getReturnValue();
var_dump([
    'html' => $html,
]);
```

- \HeadlessChromium\Page::NETWORK_IDLE fires after the page is actually generated :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Would you please check this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484243/chromium-and-chromedriver-do-not-work-correctly-permission-denied